# Session Management in an Android apps

Tags: android, session

I wanna know what is the best practice in managing user session in an android apps, is it better to check sessions on the server side **php** in my case *or* it is more paractical to use the `SharedPreferences` class on **android** and what is the difference between this two ways of programming?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Either way if you want to authenticate user via a Login after a certain minutes of being idle you have to use SharedPreferences to implement a Session Timeout.

Comment: You can controle that after communicating to the server and then you can redirect to the login page.

Comment: Here is the thing. If you want to add a Session Timeout, the elapsed time is calculated on the device and when the user interacts with the app after elapsing the defined Timeout, the app should finish all Activities and prompt the Login. That defined Timeout could be a hard coded one on the device side or a configurable one in server side which is to be fetched to the device at some point.